# Monaco editor - Capitalized functions are recognized as classes

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

As the title says, i'm using monaco editor with custom typescript code. The example above is to demonstrate the question:

```
var Scheduler = {
    configModel: function (): SchedulerConfig {
        return null;
    },

    ConfigModelCap: function (): SchedulerConfig {
        return null;
    },
}
```

Adding to the edior, works like a charm, but "configModel" allways show as function (white) and "ConfigModelCap" always show as class (green):

[image: example]

It's possible to configure it to work equal in both cases?

Comment: Looking at the stackoverflow syntax highlight, the same issue occurs ahuahauhaua

Answer (score 0):

This might be the result of semantic highlighting, though I'm not 100% sure.

However, the code convention for JS and TS code is to use camel case, with variables/constants/fields starting with a lower case letter, while classes, enums, interfaces etc. use title case.

Comment: Ok about that, but there's a way to configure to change it?
I've a lot of an old framework writed like that.